# How to make 2 histograms of a row from a table using half the n of columns per graph (R)?

Tags: r, function, histogram

I need help with histograms. I'm very new to R so I'm a bit lost even though there is probably a very easy way to solve this. 
I need write a function that returns two histograms created with data from one row of a data frame. The histograms should appear on the same plot, one above the other. 
The first histogram should consist of columns 5:39 from row 1, the second one of columns 40:74. 
I keep getting an all black plot though, or the error "x must be numeric".

Here's part of the data frame, the first columns of 74

```
          gene_id            gene_symbol                      Chr                  Biotype        L001P        L003P        L004P
1     ENSG00000000003                 TSPAN6                        X           protein_coding  3.18003e+01  6.73098e+01  6.30330e+01
2     ENSG00000000005                   TNMD                        X           protein_coding  3.72353e-02  2.28841e+00  3.29320e-02
3     ENSG00000000419                   DPM1                       20           protein_coding  1.75575e+01  4.37474e+01  2.10119e+01
4     ENSG00000000457                  SCYL3                        1           protein_coding  2.68196e+00  3.70790e+00  3.14505e+00
5     ENSG00000000460               C1orf112                        1           protein_coding  5.32179e-01  2.46598e+00  1.11985e+00
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
> data <- read.table("file", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 data1 = data[1, 5:39]
```

This gave me a vector with columns 5 to 39, including headers. However when I try to plot the first histogram, by doing this I get an all black plot

```
 hist(table(data1), 
     main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
     xlab="Patient",
     ylab="Expression level value",
     border = "black",
     col = "black")
```

[image]
What am I doing wrong? :(

Also, how should I combine the two histograms once I figure out how to plot them? Can it be done by using

```
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
```

after >return inside the function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to specify what column of the data frame you want plotted. I'm a bit confused by the question, you would usually plot columns in R, not rows. Can you provide an example of what you're expecting?

Comment: This is what I am supposed to be doing: "Write a function called histogramX, which produces two histograms (arranged on two rows) with expression levels for a single gene. The function takes as input the data, the indices of the tumor columns, the indices of non-tumor columns and the gene to be plotted."
Now, the non-tumor columns are columns 5:39, each column represents the expression level for one patient, each row one different gene. I am confused as well because I don't fully understand how I am supposed to isolate the first row of columns 5:39 and treat those values as a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it because each element is unique, for example in your tiny example

`

```
table( as.numeric( data1))

31.8003       63.033      67.3098 
      1            1             1
```

`

this is like uniform distribution, it is for that reason your problem graph 
(exist only one frequency)

i create data and i put my own example

```
data=cbind(matrix(NA,5,4),rbind(
abs(rnorm(70,54,19)),
abs(rnorm(70,0.78,1.3)),
abs(rnorm(70,27,14)),
abs(rnorm(70,3.1,0.51)),
abs(rnorm(70,1.3,0.99))
))
for (i in seq(nrow(data))) {

    win.graph()

    par(mfcol=c(1,2)) 

    data1 = data[i, 5:39]

    hist(as.numeric(data1), 
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black")

    data2 = data[i, 40:74]

    hist(as.numeric(data2), 
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black")

}
```

if you want to do one or one you can do that

win.graph()

```
    par(mfcol=c(1,2)) 

    data1 = data[1, 5:39]

    hist(as.numeric(data1), 
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black")

    data2 = data[1, 40:74]

    hist(as.numeric(data2), 
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black")
```

[image]

and if you want to do all row in your case i think this code have to function,

`

```
for (i in seq(nrow(data))) {

    win.graph()

    par(mfcol=c(1,2)) 

    data1 = data[i, 5:39]

    hist(as.numeric(data1), 
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black")

    data2 = data[i, 40:74]

    hist( as.numeric( data2),        
        main="Expression levels for TSPAN6 in non-tumor tissue",
        xlab="Patient",
        ylab="Expression level value",
        border = "black",
        col = "black") 

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Because your data is wide format, simply convert your one-row of numeric values to a numeric vector than pass into histogram plot. No need to run `table` which creates a very deeply, nested and dense array with levels equal to number of columns!

Adjust below to run inside needed function with parameter inputs for gene_id and column indices for tumor/non-tumor columns.

```
gene_param = "ENSG00000000003"

hist(as.numeric(data[data$gene_id==gene_param, 5:39]), 
     main=paste("Espression levels for TSPAN6\nin non-tumor tissue for gene,", gene_param),
     xlab="Patient", breaks=50,
     ylab="Espression level value",
     border = "black",
     col = "black")

hist(as.numeric(data[data$gene_id==gene_param, 40:74]), 
     main=paste("Espression levels for TSPAN6\nin tumor tissue for gene,", gene_param),
     xlab="Patient",
     ylab="Espression level value",
     border = "black",
     col = "black")
```

With below data supplementing with random data for columns until 74:

```
txt <- '          gene_id            gene_symbol                      Chr                  Biotype        L001P        L002P        L003P
1     ENSG00000000003                 TSPAN6                        X           protein_coding  3.18003e+01  6.73098e+01  6.30330e+01
2     ENSG00000000005                   TNMD                        X           protein_coding  3.72353e-02  2.28841e+00  3.29320e-02
3     ENSG00000000419                   DPM1                       20           protein_coding  1.75575e+01  4.37474e+01  2.10119e+01
4     ENSG00000000457                  SCYL3                        1           protein_coding  2.68196e+00  3.70790e+00  3.14505e+00
5     ENSG00000000460               C1orf112                        1           protein_coding  5.32179e-01  2.46598e+00  1.11985e+00'

data <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)

# ADDING COLUMNS OF RANDOM DATA
set.seed(41719)
data[paste0("LOO", 4:74, "P")] <- replicate(71, abs(rnorm(5))+10)
```

Running above `histogram` calls, below plots are generated with *gene_id* in title:

[image: Plot Output]